# UIButton in a custom UIView trouble

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a simple (view-based) application. I want on tapping on custom UIView my button moved somewhere inside that view (for example to point 10,10).

1. My custom UIView is DrawView (DrawView.h and DrawView.m).
2. RotatorViewController (h. and .m).

I add to my DrawView an UIButton, connect with outlets my DrawView and UIButton. I add UITapGestureRecognizer in RotatorViewController and @selector(tap:).
Here is code of UITapGestureRecognizer

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIGestureRecognizer *tapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:drawView action:@selector(tap:)];
    [drawView addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];
    [tapGR release];

}
```

@selector(tap:)

```
- (void) tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
        myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(10, 10);
}
```

But when i tap anywhere in DrawView application crashes. Here is log from console

```
2011-02-23 20:59:24.897 Rotator[7345:207] -[DrawView tap:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d0fa80
2011-02-23 20:59:24.900 Rotator[7345:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DrawView tap:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d0fa80'
```

I need your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said :

> UITapGestureRecognizer in
>   RotatorViewController and
>   @selector(tap:)

and you wrote : 
 `UIGestureRecognizer *tapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:drawView action:@selector(tap:)];`

It means the actions is performed in the drawView delegate but you defined the selector `tap:` in the `RotatorViewController`.

I think you just have to replace the target `drawView` by `self`

`UIGestureRecognizer *tapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)];`

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that instances of the `DrawView` class do not respond to `tap:` messages. I see that you have defined a `tap:` method in `DrawView.m`, but have you *declared* that method in the header? Like so:

> **DrawView.h**

```
@class UITapGestureRecognizer;
@interface DrawView {
    UIButton *myButton;
}
- (void) tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture;
@end
```

Comment: no, seems that selectors no need to be declared in header file. Thank you for your thoughts!